# addTarget not working properly

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having trouble getting addTarget to work when I swap the buttons programmatically

```
        let leftButton: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
        leftButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "menu"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        leftButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24)
        ...
        leftButton.addTarget(nil, action: #selector(MapViewController.backToModules(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        ...
        let leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: leftButton)
        let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: rightButton)
        //assign button to navigationbar
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [rightBarButton]
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton
```

My target should call the following function, but it doesn't?

```
func backToModules(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing target parameter (I assume it's `self`):

```
leftButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MapViewController.backToModules(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

When adding target, you have to specify `selector` that determines the identifier of the method to call - you managed to do that. However, you have to also give it a target object, an object on which that selector is supposed to be called - and that you specified as `nil`. That means that the selector was called on `nil` object.

In your case, the first target parameter has to be object of type `MapViewController` on which the method defined by the selector (`backToModules(sender:)`) will be called. If you call that `addTarget` method in context of `MapViewController` instance that should be the target, then use `self` as I suggested.

Comment: Not quite right to say it was not called at all. `nil` targeted actions are a thing. If a handler for selector had been found in the responder chain, it would indeed have been called.